# nodejs: Print a Hebrew RTL string to the shell

Tags: node.js, shell, unicode, right-to-left, hebrew

The following JS Object contains Hebrew Strings:

```
  { stationId: 359,
    location: { lat: 32.0732, lon: 34.7859, address: 'קפלן פינת ארניה' },
    bikes: { availableBikes: 12, availableParkingSlots: 16 } },
  { stationId: 116,
    location: { lat: 32.1022, lon: 34.7854, address: 'שי עגנון 59' },
    bikes: { availableBikes: 5, availableParkingSlots: 13 } },
  { stationId: 314,
    location: { lat: 32.0917, lon: 34.7826, address: 'נורדאו 101בשדרה' },
    bikes: { availableBikes: 9, availableParkingSlots: 10 } },
```

However, when the object is printed to the shell (`iTerm2` with `zsh`), the Hebrew strings are shown as LTR (first letter is on the left-hand side of the string, instead of the right-hand side as it should).

[image: Object in shell]

Note that this problem can not be solved by simply reversing the string, because it would also reverse numbers and English words which should appear LTR.

**How can I correctly print the Hebrew RTL strings to the shell in nodejs?**

Comment: @Adan why do you need it on the shell (iTerm2)? I see your problem, But the problem does not occur when I use WebStorm (https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/).

Comment: Because I am building a CLI tool that writes the Tel Aviv city bike availability for a given station. Its address is written in Hebrew.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is with iTerm2, not node.js. iTerm2 does not properly supports RTL. See https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/issues/1611.

Using standard Mac OS X Terminal should display the text properly.